# jquery .load issue (problems in loaded divs)

Tags: ajax

when i use this code,the jquery code in the #paylasimlar does not run.i search a lot.some say

use .ajax some say do not use bind.load.but none of them works.what can i do if i want codes

run in both places?

```
$('#paylasimlar').load('profile.php #paylasimlar');
```

(shortly i submit an information and i want to load the section that these information are shown,and there are comment sections below informations whixh work with jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.load()` requires a callback function, and runs the function when the item gets added to the DOM.

So generally you do:

```
$('#paylasimlar').load(function(){ 
    do Something
});
```

is this what you are looking for?  If not you may want to look at `$.ajax()` or `$.get()`

Comment: no i am talking about the method .load to refresh the parts of page

Answer (score 0):

I have to load one index.php file inside another index file. Include() didn't help me at all but load() did!I have no "do something" as mentioned above.
It did at least loaed the second index.php inside the other one, but well not peoperly(the page jumps out)!

My question is that could 'not having "do something"' be the reason?